# Creating Navigation Property without foreign key?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, linq, entity

I am trying to create a navigation property for my data model using an existing database.  The data has a shared key (like a foreign key) however it is not specified that way in the database.  Here is what it looks like:

```
 [Table("Alpha")]
    public class Alpha
    {
        public int AlphaID { get; set; }

        public int AlphaGroupID { get; set; }

        public int? ParentAlphaID { get; set; }

        public int? CodeID { get; set; }

        public int? BracketCodeID { get; set; }

        public string Title { get; set; }
    }





[Table("AlphaGroup")]
    public class AlphaGroup
    {
        [Column("AlphaGroupID")]
        public int AlphaGroupID { get; set; }

        public string Title { get; set; }

        public string TitleAddon { get; set; }

    }
```

AlphaGroupID needs to be a navigation property to AlphaGroupID but is not a foreign key.  Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one way can be using the icollection in the parent class like in your example:

```
public virtual ICollection<AlphaGroup> AlphaGroup { get; set; }
```